# Is there a way to get the posted street speed limits in nokia location api?

Tags: here-api

Is there a way to get the posted street speed limits in nokia location api?

Is there any web based API service which provides street speed limits for the united states?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the `getLinkInfo` endpoint from the [Enterprise Routing API.](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing). The `speedLimit` element returned is in **m/s** so multiply by 3.6 for **km/h** or 2.23 for **mph**. If the `speedLimit` element is missing then the national speed limit applies.

[http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=**your_app_id**&app_code=**your_app_code**](http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

Comment: This will no longer be supported after March 31, 2017.  You will have to use PDE

Answer (score 0):

Since Jason answer is outdated, you should now use/migrate to **Here API** which is newer and faster.

- You have to use different endpoint.
- SpeedLimit is returned in **m/s** aswell.

You can make request with:

- **GPS coordinates** ([doc](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/link-information-for-a-location)):

or

- **linkId** ([doc](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/get-link-info-from-id))